# Authenticating across different subdomains (but not all)

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, cookies, http-authentication

I have a site set up on `www.domain.com`, the site can authenticate users and persist their credentials in a cookie.

On occasions the users access handlers that are set up on different servers on a different sub domain. `handlers.domain.com`

I can't afford to use wildcard subdomain cookies (Cookies should not be available for other subdomains)

My solution for access control up until now was that every URL used for `handlers.domain.com` had a guid specific to the user. The handlers on the other site would assume the identity of the guid owner. This of course is not such a good security practice.

i was thinking about an alternative solution: All links to `handlers.domain.com` will actually be links to a redirector script on `www.domain.com` that will redirect to an encrypted time stamped url on `handlers.domain.com` which will then know for sure that it was accessed as a direct authenticated redirection from `www.domain.com`.
This solution will work fine on GET scenarios but will fail with handlers expecting POST data (up do big uploaded files)

Does anyone know or can think of a better solution or have any insight on my solution?

(In this case I am using ASP.NET but the solution will probably be platform agnostic, so I will tag this with various web platforms)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not want to use cookies to establish a session (group of requests) you need to find other ways. As the information of the cookie is passed readable within the HTTP request, I do not see a problem if you for that one particular request pass that information as part of a POST request.

If you prefer a GET request I would additionally add a flag inside the users server-side session prior the redirect so to give the script that is the destination of the redirect the possibility to verify the validity of the request on the server-side.

Comment: I do establish a session, but only on the first subdomain. perhaps, and this is a pure ASP.NET issue now, I can post the sessionId with the POST request and "join" the session in the other domain (I do use a central db session management), I am not sure this can be done however in ASP.NET

Comment: You'd probably have to override the default session module to do that, but it may be possible.

Comment: Session was merely used as a broad term in my answer. You can for example place that flag into the database and then query that flag from the database on the other server regardless which type of "session module" is used. Just pass data server-side only to verify that the request is valid. If you use cryptography, you would share the secret key server-side. But with cryptography you need to know what you're doing and how to behave if the secret key get's tampered or lost. With the "session" (shared storage between both servers), you will have one "secret" for each request.

Comment: I like that idea... As for the POST issue, I assume there probably isn't any better way then suppling the identification data in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You said you "can't afford to use wildcard subdomain cookies (Cookies should not be available for other subdomains)".  Does that mean you can't afford it monetarily or you you don't want the user to have access to all subdomains?  If it's the second, you could still use subdomain cookies by putting in an encrypted value with that user's ID and check it versus access permissions on your various subdomains.  That keeps everything at the server where it's more secure versus at the URL level.  The only way a potential hacker can get past it is to guess another user's ID and figure out your keys for properly encrypting it.

Comment: I pay my ISP 10$ per cookie per subdomain so it's getting rather expensive... (kidding)

Comment: The reason I don't want to use wildcard domain cookies is because other subdomins server the staging, development and demo versions of the site and I don't want the cookies to mix.